# Equal height elements with CSS

Tags: css, html

I read about several different solutions to simulate equal-height columns or elements, but none of them really captured my attention because they were using hacks, incredibly complex HTML layouts or not widely supported attributes.

Here's the example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weppos/satgw/).

My goal would be to make sure all the elements have the same height or, at least, the maximum height of the siblings in the row.

A row is composed by 3 elements (in this case, no row wrapper exists but I may consider to add such container element).

Is there a solution that:

1. doesn't require JS
2. [doesn't use `display: table`](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/equal_height/)
3. doesn't use wide padding/margin with negative values
4. [doesn't require exponential uses of divs and float](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the restrictions you made: No, there isn't.

edit: Because you didn't mention this: You could use tables for this. (welcome back to the 90s)

Comment: I was thinking the same. Still, I'm hoping that maybe someone smarter than me will be able to come with a solution. That's why I upvoted the question and favorited it.

Comment: @Ana I have the same feeling, this is the reason of my question.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti to make sure: I presumed you want to have dynamic height columns and not some fixed height stuff.

Comment: @Christoph that's right. I could have used fixed height but I was looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS3 **flex** property for this. Write like this:

```
CSS

.parent{
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    width:100%;
    min-height:200px;
}

.parent div{
    background:red;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    border:2px solid green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/VkPmg/2/

Comment: Pretty cool. Does it work with IE? (at least the latest releases).

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Nope, it doesn't which is why i didn't tell you this solution: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: This indeed might be interesting, but i don't want to see the performance of this in IE6...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fix width layout, you can fake it by background-image. Imagine a tile image background that simulate the borders, you will just have to repeat-y in the main container.

For example if you have a 400px container with 3 100px box floating (like your fiddle), you will have to make a 1x400 image repeating in the main container. Just add in this image at the good x position 1 pixel look like the border color you used. And repeat it !

With this technique, your box will not have the same height (in reality) but the display will look like the boxe have it because the higher box will push the container and the background will appear.

Comment: I can't use this hack because the use of CSS rounded corners doesn't apply very well to this solution.